# Testing for Goodness of Fit

Tags: python, dictionary, chi-squared, goodness-of-fit

Scipy has a fairly good way of calculating goodness of fit using arrays.

```
import scipy, scipy.stats.chisquare

observed_values=scipy.array([1,1]) 
expected_values=scipy.array([2,2]) 

chisquare(observed_values, f_exp=expected_values)

def chisquare(observed_values,expected_values): #Calculating the value for the test statistic,x^2
    test_statistic=0
    for observed, expected in zip(observed_values, expected_values):
        test_statistic+=(float(observed)-float(expected))**2/float(expected)
        return test_statistic
```

Besides this, is there another method to test for goodness of fit in general?

Comment: How is your dictionary structured? Yes you will need to convert to array-like which shouldn't be any trouble. Be careful though because dictionaries will always be sorted by key unless you are using an `OrderedDict`.